# Symfony2 php composer.phar install

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

When I was setting up Symfony 2 in that step

```
php composer.phar install
```

It gives me that error

> Script Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
>
> [InvalidArgumentException]
>    The dist file "app/config/parameters.yml.dist" does not exist. Check your dist-file config or create it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check your `parameters.yml.dist` file? Does it exists? It should be placed in `app/config/parameters.yml.dist`

Comment: I copied the file to app/config and still same error

Comment: I just did , but no change

Comment: Check file `vendor/incenteev/composer-parameter-handler/Incenteev/ParameterHandler/Processor.php`, method `processConfig`, there's line `!is_file($config['dist-file'])` which causes this exception. Try debug this one, it should be quite straight-forward